# Create Extra Large Table in R

Tags: r, datatable, grid, bigdata

I need to generate big table which contents more than billion rows.
Existing I use expand.grid(rep(list(n),k)) but the error message raised saying that need to allocate memory.
I don't it's a proper way to generate the data or is there more efficient way to do. Please advice

Comment: what are `n` and `k`?

Comment: novica, n and k are any number, eq n= 1:3 and k=4